# how to reduce DynamoDB GSI item size when nested attributes are involved

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDB limits query response size to 1MB, so to maximize the number of items returned per query, I would like to reduce the size of an individual item. Since I query by GSI, one natural approach is to reduce the number of attributes projected. The problem is that a few of the attributes that I need is a nested attribute and not a top-level attribute. Including the top-level attribute will make the items entries in GSI too large.

I am aware there is no way to project a nested attribute in a GSI. Is there any work-around to reduce the item size while allowing me to access nested attribute within a single query?

Comment: If your data model isn’t working for the functionality you desire, change your data model.

Answer (score 0):

I want to start by saying that your first assumption, that DynamoDB `Query` is limited to 1MB, is incorrect. Indeed, `Query` will return results after having read 1MB of data, but you can continue fetching the next results - a process known as *paging*. Please refer to the `Query` documentation where it is clearly explained how to do it.

If, despite learning this, you still want to retrieve only pieces of each item and not the entire items, that's easy to do - using a [ProjectionExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html). If you pass a `ProjectionExpression` during a `Query`, it will return only parts of the retrieved items. It even allows you to return only a piece of a nested attribute, exactly like you wanted.

Be aware, though, that even if you only retrieve small pieces of large items, you will still *pay* for retrieving the entire item. That's a benefit of GSI you don't get by using `ProjectionExpression` - you don't get cheaper retrieval. Also, it won't help you with the single-page query you began with, because the 1MB page cutoff happens at the item-size level, not the returned data length level. So you'll still need to implement paging and not assume that a single page is always enough.